# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Yet output is showing

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working to show editable fields based on query results. I know the query is functioning properly, and it is returning an array. The array is populating the form fields properly, however, I am getting the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" warning. I am new at this, and at a loss as to what is happening. I appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the code:

```
// Grab the profile data from the database
$query8 = "SELECT * FROM EDUCATION WHERE ID_NUM = '" . $_SESSION['IDNUM'] . "' ORDER BY RECORD";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query8);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>'; 
$rowcount = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    if (is_array($row))
    {
        echo '<p> It is an Array</p>';
    }
    foreach($row as &$item)
    {
        $record = $row['RECORD'];
        $school = $row['SCHOOL'];
        $type = $row['TYPE'];
        $degree = $row['DEGREE'];
        $major = $row['MAJOR'];
        $grad = $row['GRAD'];

        ?>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Education History </legend>
        <?php
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="record" name="record" value="' . $record . '">';
        echo 'Rowcount' . $rowcount. '</br>';
        // Insert Listbox here
        $queryschool = "SELECT * FROM SCHOOL";
        $list = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryschool);
        if($list) 
        {
            echo 'School Type? ';
            echo '<select name="school_code">';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list))
            {
                echo "<option value={$row['CODE']}>{$row['TYPE']}" ;
                echo '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }

        echo '<br />';
        echo '<label for="school">School Name:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="school" name="school" size="40" maxlength="40" value="' . ( (!empty($school)) ? $school : "") . '" /><br />';

        // Insert Listbox here
        $querydegree = "SELECT * FROM DEGREE";
        $list = mysqli_query($dbc, $querydegree);
        if($list) 
        {
            echo 'Degree Type? ';
            echo '<select name="degree_code">';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list))
            {
                echo "<option value={$row['CODE']}>{$row['DEGREE']}";
                echo '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<label for="major">Field of study:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="major" name="major" size="40" maxlength="40" value="' . ( (!empty($major)) ? $major : "") . '" /><br />';
        echo '<label for="grad">Did you graduate?:</label>';
        echo '<input type="radio" id="grad" name="grad" value="Y" ' . ($grad == "Y" ? 'checked="checked"':'') . '/>Yes ';
        echo '<input type="radio" id="grad" name="grad" value="N" ' . ($grad == "N" ? 'checked="checked"':'') . '/>No<br />';
        ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php
        $rowcount++;
    }
}
;
echo '<label for="another">Do you need to enter more educational experience?:</label>';
echo '<input type="radio" id="another" name="another" value="Y" ' . ($another == "Y" ? 'checked="checked"':'') . '/>Yes ';
echo '<input type="radio" id="another" name="another" value="N" ' . ($another == "N" ? 'checked="checked"':'') . '/>No<br />';

?>

<input type="submit" value="Save Profile" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($row as &$item)
```

replace this with:

```
foreach ($row as $item)
```

And then for each variable you should probably change

```
$record = $row['RECORD'];
```

to

```
$record = $item['RECORD'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach($row as &$item)` should be

```
 foreach($row as $item)
```

there is no need to use the foreach here  you can just do this like  like

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
{

$record = $row['RECORD'];
$school = $row['SCHOOL'];
$type = $row['TYPE'];
$degree = $row['DEGREE'];
$major = $row['MAJOR'];
$grad = $row['GRAD'];
}
```

Comment: That change does eliminate the error message.  Now the problem is that the radio button in each instance of the fieldset is functioning as one. Selecting 'Yes' on one row de-selects all other rows. And my drop down boxes are not defaulting to the previously selected item, and throught the submit button, no changes are being saved.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the row item, so don't pass by reference to the foreach. Also, shouldn't you be using $item instead of $row?   Do this:

```
foreach($row as $item)
 {
  $record = $item['RECORD'];
  $school = $item['SCHOOL'];
  ....
```

Don't do This:

```
foreach($row as &$item)
  {
  $record = $row['RECORD'];
  $school = $row['SCHOOL'];
  ....
```

Comment: When I make the change to using $item['field'] the output to the form truncates that data and multiplies the iterations?  I am wanting to be able to change the data through the form.